# How to pass url as rest service?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to build a rest service in spring boot to update my database..

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/setrepacking/{transaction_number}/{image_url}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String setRepackingDetails(@PathVariable String transaction_number,
                                     @PathVariable  String image_url) {

    dao.setRepackingDetails(transaction_number, image_url);
    return "Updated repacking details for "+transaction_number;
   }
```

But my image_url is like below:  And I want to pass below as part of rest component

> http://xxxx.com/api/images/get?format=src&type=png

I am trying something like below:

```
`www.localhost:8080/setrepacking/3500574684/http://thecatapi.com/api/images`/get?format=src&type=png
```

It is not accepting...

How do I pass the parameter in my broswer??
Appricate  any quick solution....

Comment: This is not possible because you are trying to call http call inside http URL.There is an solution that you have to call first get image URL and send this response to another URL .

Comment: you can pass an other URL within a URI by encoding the value beforehand using [URL encoding/decoding](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

Comment: @Darshan I have to update the url in database taking from browser..So how can I take this from browser.If I can collect from browser then I can do other operations...

Answer (score 1):

You have to URL encode your image URL path variable before passing it in the request, encoded URL looks like this:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fxxxx.com%2Fapi%2Fimages%2Fget%3Fformat%3Dsrc%26type%3Dpng
```

So you request has to look like this:

http://localhost:8080/setrepacking/3500574684/http%3A%2F%2Fxxxx.com%2Fapi%2Fimages%2Fget%3Fformat%3Dsrc%26type%3Dpng

This way you will get your image URL correctly. Also have a look at [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) and [URLDecoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html)